# CSS and JS return 404 in only custom module page (in admin panel)

Tags: magento2

I write custom module for admin panel. The entire admin panel works correctly. Styles and scripts are loaded everywhere. But custom module page looks like [image]

I checked source code. Valid CSS path looks like `http://test.ru/static/version1663599491/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_EN/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css`

But in custom module page I have this - `<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://test.ru/static/version1663599491/adminhtml/_view/en_EN/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />` and this file return 404.

How to fix this problem?

P.S. Magento v 2.4.2.

Comment: Have you tried running your static file deploy? `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Yes. The strangeness is that the whole admin panel works, the problem is only in one module.

Comment: How are you importing the file into your module? Are you using a layout file, or are you including it in the PHTML directly? If you are including it directly that may be the issue, magento may be minifying the file and serving at yourfile.min.css or the version number may have changed since you included it. It is typically best to include it using a layout file, as magento will handle determining the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in OPcache. He cached them very much, so the site as a whole did not work correctly.